# Access ResourceDictionary from another assembly in Code

Tags: c#, wpf

In my library I want to create `TabItem`s in a method. The `TabItem`s should use a `Template` which is defined in a `ResourceDictionary` in another assembly.

While searching for a solution I found the following code:

```
ResourceDictionary res = (ResourceDictionary) Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("BaseLib.WPF.Skinning;component/BaseStyles.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

If I execute the code I get a `FileNotFoundException` within the target-assembly. The assembly `BaseLib.WPF.Skinning` is added as reference to the project.

How can I access my `ResourceDictionary` from my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
`Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/BaseLib.WPF.Skinning;component/BaseStyles.xaml")`
```

Uri need's String type argument ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: With this code I get an `ArgumentException` `Absolut uri can not be used`

Comment: Thanks @Amol Bavannavar. I missed quotes.