# How to reference a ResourceDictionary from another assembly

Tags: wpf, resources, styles, resourcedictionary

I have a ResourceDictionary defined in my App.xaml like that:

```
<Application x:Class="Controller.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MyDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now, since im using PRISM, i would would like to use the styles that are in "MyDictionary.xaml" in my other modules/assemblies within my application.

The problem is that i can access to this styles in some modules just like:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource myLblStyle}"/>
```

But in another module i cant access to the same style.
I always get the error **"The resource "myLblStyle" could not be resolved"**.

So far i couldn't find any difference between the modules that can access the resource and the modules that cant.
I was reading a lot about the PackUri etc. but all this couldn't solve my problem.

Is there anything else i have to define or do in the modules? At the modules that work i didn't do anything. I can just access the Styles via:

```
Style="{StaticResource myLblStyle}"/>
```

Comment: try with DynamicResource...Style="{DynamicResource myLblStyle}"/>

Comment: @ Heena: This gives me the same problem. No change.

Comment: you should read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @dev hedgehog: Thank you. I have read this already. But this link still does not tell me if i have to reference/load or do whatever in my module to be able to access the styles in my resources. My i overlooked it.

Comment: @ck84vi that's not possible.. read it again then :) that article is exactly about referencing resources using packs

Comment: @dev hedgehog: I read it again and changed my Res definition to <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/MyDictionary.xaml" /> which gives me exactly the same problem. BUT, after some more google search i found the problem [here](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/444815). It has nothing to do with the PACK etc. i think. Its just that during design time the modules have no access to the resource dictionary.

Comment: Did you checked this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243337/access-resourcedictionary-from-another-assembly-in-code

Comment: @ck84vi you should have mentioned that you are seeking a solution for design time.. be more specific next time